# How to customize Search Suggestion UI which show details in a hierarchical model

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-xml

How to implement a view which contains an EditText ,whenever we type something it should show categories and items in the individual category as shown in the image.

[image: Custom suggestion ui]

Answer (score 0):

Such view can be implemented as https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html?hl=en popup windows, which get updated/recreated on each change in EditText